# How to concatenate string and int in C?

Tags: c, string

I need to form a string, inside each iteration of the loop, which contains the loop index `i`:

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++) {
  // Shown in java-like code which I need working in c!

  String prefix = "pre_";
  String suffix = "_suff";

  // This is the string I need formed:
  //  e.g. "pre_3_suff"
  String result = prefix + i + suffix;
}
```

I tried using various combinations of `strcat` and `itoa` with no luck.

Comment: show us what you've tried instead of what you want, you'll learn much more with comments on your code than people telling you what to do

Comment: State your problem in full... it seems you are having a problem but which problem you didn't mentioned? the string is not forming or what?

Comment: @SMKamran: This is not his code. It's Java-style pseudocode. His problem is that he doesn't know how to do this in C.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Strings are hard work in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i;
   char buf[12];

   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      snprintf(buf, 12, "pre_%d_suff", i); // puts string into buffer
      printf("%s\n", buf); // outputs so you can see it
   }
}
```

The `12` is enough bytes to store the text `"pre_"`, the text `"_suff"`, a string of up to two characters (`"99"`) and the NULL terminator that goes on the end of C string buffers.

[This](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) will tell you how to use `snprintf`, but I suggest a good C book!

Comment: I want to give +1, but the first line of your answer rather contradicts the rest of it. You've shown that in fact the solution is easy; you just have to throw out the notion that inefficient string concatenation idioms from script languages translate over to C. `snprintf` is the answer to almost any C string-assembly question.

Comment: @R. What I've shown is that the solution is not quite as easy as the OP was hoping. "Just" throwing out that notion is harder for some than for others.

Comment: Also you should be using `snprintf`, not `sprintf`. I missed that on the first read. Your code is very dangerous as written, since if the 100 is changed without updating the buffer size, you'll clobber the stack.

Comment: @R. When you change the 100, you change the buffer size. Using `snprintf` does not change that; it just means that you have one more place to write and update the buffer size.

Comment: The difference is that your code crashes (or worse yet yields a privilege compromise) when somebody forgets to change the buffer size, while the version with `snprintf` just truncates the string. In any case I would make the buffer size `12+3*sizeof(int)` and then you don't have to worry... but it would still be better to use `snprintf`.

Comment: @delive: What do you mean by "not work"? What actually happened for you?

Answer (score 9):

Use `sprintf` (or `snprintf` if like me you can't count) with format string `"pre_%d_suff"`.

For what it's worth, with itoa/strcat you could do:

```
char dst[12] = "pre_";
itoa(i, dst+4, 10);
strcat(dst, "_suff");
```

Comment: "what's `itoa`"?

Comment: According to [a C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), regarding `itoa`, it is stated that "This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers."

Comment: @AnttiHaapala--СлаваУкраїні, itoa converts an int to a char string.

Comment: @Koldsoar the quotes mean: the function is not part of the standard C library.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [snprintf](http://libslack.org/manpages/snprintf.3.html) or, if GNU extensions are OK, [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) (which will allocate memory for you).

Comment: Allocating the memory "for you" is hardly doing you a favor. There's a small constant bound on the size needed, so it makes much more sense to provide the buffer yourself. With `asprintf` you'd have to add a test for allocation failure and code to free the buffer later.