# C++ int to string, concatenate strings

Tags: c++, string, g++

I'm new to C++ and working on a simple project. Basically where I'm encountering a problem is creating a file with a number (int) in the file name. As I see it,I have to first convert the int to a string (or char array) and then concatenate this new string with the rest of the file name.

Here is my code so far that fails to compile:

```
int n; //int to include in filename
char buffer [33];
itoa(n, buffer, 10);
string nStr = string(buffer);

ofstream resultsFile;
resultsFile.open(string("File - ") + nStr + string(".txt"));
```

This gives a couple compilation errors (compiling in Linux):

1. itoa not declared in this scope
2. no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream char, std::char_traits char ::open(std::basic_string char, std::char_traits char , std::allocator char )’

I've tried the advice here: [c string and int concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172107/c-string-and-int-concatenation)
and here: [Easiest way to convert int to string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c) with no luck.

If I using the to_string method, I end up with the error "to_string not a member of std".

Comment: If you can afford C++11, a much easier way to convert an integer to a string is to use `std::to_string`. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `stringstream` to construct the filename.

```
std::ostringstream filename;
filename << "File - " << n << ".txt";
resultsFile.open(filename.str().c_str());
```

Comment: This looks promising. However when I compile the code I get the error:
"aggregate ‘std::ostringstream filename’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined"

Comment: I don't recognise that error. You need to `#include <sstream>` at the top of your source file.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `boost::lexical_cast`.  You also need to include any needed headers:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast>
#include <string>
std::string nStr = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(n);
```

then it's simply:

```
std::string file_name = "File-" + nStr + ".txt";
```

because `std::strng` plays nicely with string literals (e.g. ".txt").

Comment: Or if you don't have either, use a stringstream.

Answer (score 1):

For `itoa`, you are likely missing `#include <stdlib.h>`. Note that `itoa` is non-standard: the standard ways to format an integer as string as `sprintf` and `std::ostringstream`.

`ofstream.open()` takes a `const char*`, not `std::string`. Use `.c_str()` method to obtain the former from the latter.

Putting it together, you are looking for something like this:

```
ostringstream nameStream;
nameStream << "File - " << n << ".txt";
ofstream resultsFile(nameStream.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "File - "  << nStr << ".txt";
std::ofstream resultsFile(os.str().c_str());
```

Using [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) (C++11):

```
std::string filename = "File - " + std::to_string(nStr) + ".txt";
std::ofstream resultsFile(filename.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

for itoa function

```
include <stdlib.h>
```

consider this link

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: #include, not include.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::stringstream`

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "File - " << n << ".txt";
```

Since the constructor requires a char pointer, you need to convert it into a char pointer using

```
ofstream resultsFile(ss.str().c_str());
```