# How to add a number to a string at the end in a c program?

Tags: c

I need to write a function which will take a string as input and outputs as below

```
input : aaabbdd
output : a3b2d2

input : aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbccc
output : a16b2c3
```

basically I have to append the count to every character. I should not use itoa() to convert int to string

I wrote the logic. But I got struck at appending the number to the string. For example, if count is 16, how can I add the number 16 to end of a string?

My logic is as given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void str1(char *str)
{
    int i, j, cnt;

    int len = strlen(str);

    char *nstr = (char *) malloc(len * sizeof(char));

    int k = 0;
    cnt = 1;

    for(i = 0, j = 1; i < len - 1;)
    {
        if(str[i] == str[j])
        {
            j++;
            cnt++;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if(cnt == 1)
            {
                nstr[k++] = str[i];
            }
            else
            {
                nstr[k++] = str[i];
                nstr[k++] = cnt; // GOT STUCK HERE
            }
            i = j;
            j = i + 1;
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", nstr);
}

main()
{
    char str[] = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbcdd";

    str1(str);
}
```

Comment: show some code, what you got, what won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c string and int concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172107/c-string-and-int-concatenation)

Comment: please post what you have done so far

Comment: why do you want to store it, you are only asked to output it?

Comment: @Pieter21 : How can I output it? Are you suggesting that just print character and number instead of storing it in a buffer and printing entire string at once?

Comment: exactly what I suggest :)

Comment: @Pieter21 : Yeah. That will work. But I am preparing for interview. If they ask me to write the function which will return the string instead of printing, I will have tough times w/o practising :)

Comment: @kadina, they won't! This exercise is about keeping track of state, and not about int to string conversion.
Otherwise just say you'd strcat your way out of this with sufficiently allocated buffers.

Comment: You might want to be careful with the size of your buffer: If a single character is followed by a "1", your new string can be longer than the old one. Example: abcdefgh -> a1b1c1d1e1f1g1h1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `itoa` yourself. The logic is as follows:

- If the number is zero, append zero (in your case, this should never happen, but in general case this is obviously possible)
- Prepare a temporary buffer for your output. The size depends on the number of bits in the integer that you are printing
- Store the last digit by computing `n % 10`
- Divide the number by ten using integer division
- Continue the last three steps until the remaining part is zero
- Append the reversed sequence of digits from the temporary buffer to your output

This is only one way of implementing the logic. Other ways are possible as well - for example, you could build a lookup table of powers of ten, and compute each digit using a combination of integer division and taking the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

All the code you need, decorated with comments:

```
if (len == 0) return;

/* initialize */
char c = str[0];
int  count = 1;

/* include terminating '\0', and that will resolve itself! */
for (i = 1; i <= len; i++)
{
   if (str[i] == str[i-1])
   {
      /* continue sequence */
      count++;
   }
   else
   {
      /* end sequence */
      printf("%c%d", c, count);
      /* start new sequence */
      c = str[i]; count = 1;
   }
}
printf("\n"); /* flush buffer */
```