# How to send command to Linux command from C program

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to send a command to a Linux command line from a C program and there is one part I am not sure how to do.

For example in my C code I have

```
system("raspistill -o image.jpg");
```

What I would like to be able to do is add a number to the end of "image" and increment it every time the program runs, but how can I pass in a variable `n` to the `system()` function that is only looking for a `const char`?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
char fileName = ("raspistill -o image%d.jpg",n);
system(filename);
```

I've tried searching on this and haven't found anything about how to add a variable to it. Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Build a **string** with `sprintf` and then pass that to `system`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c string and int concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172107/c-string-and-int-concatenation)

Answer (score 2):

```
char fileName[80];

sprintf(fileName, "raspistill -o image%d.jpg",n);
system(filename);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly! I didn't realize sprintf() could be used like that.

Answer (score 0):

First, a String is a char array, so declare (I think you know, just to emphasize):

```
char command[32];
```

So, simple solution will be:

```
sprintf(command, "raspistill -o image%d.jpg", n);
```

Then call `system(command);`. This is just what you need.

---

EDIT:

**If** you **need program output**, try `popen`:

```
char command[32]; 
char data[1024];
sprintf(command, "raspistill -o image%d.jpg", n);
//Open the process with given 'command' for reading
FILE* file = popen(command, "r");
// do something with program output.
while (fgets(data, sizeof(data)-1, file) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", data);
}
pclose(file);
```

Sources: [C: Run a System Command and Get Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646241/c-run-a-system-command-and-get-output)

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html